# REST API Delete method Resource modelling

Tags: rest, restlet

I would like to design a rest API with delete method which contains optional parameters.I think it is not a recommended way to have body for delete method.Either i need to pass the parameters as a path param/query param.Can i have optional fields in path param/query param?

My resource is as below

DELETE policy/{policy-number}/{entity-type}/endorse-number

Entity type is optional.

Any help appraciated.

Answer (score 2):

The REST architectural style, defined in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy T. Fielding's dissertation, says nothing about what the URLs must be like. It defines a set of constraints that must be followed by the applications that follow such architecture.

On the other hand, the *examples* of this [article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) written by Martin Fowler explaining a model defined by Leonard Richardson *suggest* a URL structure that looks friendly and easy to read.

---

You could use a **matrix parameter**. Assuming that you want to delete the *endorse number* for a given *policy* (filtered by *entity type*), you could use:

```
DELETE /policy/{policy-number};entity-type={entity-type}/endorse-number
```

To delete the *endorse number* for a given *policy*, just remove the *entity type* filter:

```
DELETE /policy/{policy-number}/endorse-number
```